# Drush command for setting up databases

Tags: drush

I just installed Drush 9 on my ubuntu 19 machine. I also downloaded the latest Drupal 7 and 8 to my /var/www/html folder. My mysql is verified working. Is there a quick drush command to help me setup my databases without me having to manually create them for each drupal instance? I have access to my root user if needed.

Comment: If you want create database via drush there is command `drush sql:create --db-su=root --db-su-pw=rootpassword --db-url="mysql://drupal_db_user:drupal_db_password@127.0.0.1/drupal_db"
` check the documentation here https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/sql/sql:create/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the docs here: https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/sql/sql:create/

> drush sql:create --db-su=root --db-su-pw=rootpassword
>   --db-url="mysql://drupal_db_user:drupal_db_password@127.0.0.1/drupal_db"

It works on drush v8 as drush v9 doesn't support Drupal 7.